# Good ETFs for 33-year-old with ~$125K in investments

Tags: investing, roth-ira

I have around 125K spread across a 401k (with my employer), a Roth IRA, and a 529 for my daughter.

What are some of the best low-fee ETFs for someone in my situation? Wondering specifically about good Roth IRA options.

Comment: Unfortunately, recommendations for specific products are off-topic here, as is true almost everywhere on SE.  A question about how to do that evaluation yourself -- what strategies to consider for diversification and what to look for when comparing similar funds  -- would be on topic but would almost certainly be a duplicate of past questions.  I'd suggest reading through existing answers, then ask a more specific question if there is something you don't understand.